# How to get directory sizes without junctions in Far Manager

Tags: junction, far-manager

By default Far Manager includes sizes junction into the directory size (F3).

Is there a way to avoid counting them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible. Open main menu (<kbd>F9</kbd>)

`Options` → `System settings` → `[x] Scan symbolic links`

Uncheck this option, and save settings (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks! I remember I saw it somewhere many years ago but there're so many settings in the latest far and no search facility in the help section that it is practically impossible to find something.

Comment: Actually there is sort of search facility: launch `far:config` from command line and press `RAlt` to activate filter. After finding some item you can use `Shift-F1` to show help.

Comment: Cool! But I use Birman's layout so RAlt is somewhat problematic for me.

Comment: As mentioned in the [forum](http://forum.farmanager.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7184&start=16), Ctrl-Alt-f works in case RAlt is unavailable. Why not to use LAlt for search?

Comment: Looks like Total Commander [cannot calc dir size](http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=258967) without junctions without a special plugin.

Comment: Is System.ScanSymlinks and System.ScanJunction the same thing?

Comment: You can use `LAlt` for search via macro

Comment: Similar names but completely different option: `System.ScanSymlinks` belongs to `Options`→`Plugins manager settings`

Comment: Indeed so. But Shift-F1 pressed on System.ScanSymlinks in far:config points to the same place as System.ScanJunction

Comment: It works a bit oddly. When pressing F3 on a junction, it shows the size of the underlying data, as well as when selecting it by the 'Insert' key prior to hitting F3, while I'd expect it to show 0 size, like `du -s` on symlinks in linux . The total size of the parent dir is counted correctly though considering symlink to be zero-sized.

Comment: > You can use LAlt for search via macro - Yes, that's a good idea. Although it behaves in a slightly different way than Alt-<first letters of filename> that old far users are used to (alt needs to be released before entering the word). It is more of a `Ctrl-F` usage pattern in other programs.